# passar parâmetros externos para o sqlcmd via batch

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch

Eu usava no oracle assim, gostaria de saber se tem algum método parecido para o sqlserver **(sqlcmd)**.

**Batch** 
    `sqlplus.exe system/123@localhost/xe @..\CRIA_TABELAS.sql "%last_bill%"`

**arquivo .sql** 
    `SELECT * FROM TB_VENDAS_&1`

**O que o oracle interpreta** 
    `SELECT * FROM TB_VENDAS_20180901`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rafael, no SQL Server na cláusula FROM não é possível utilizar variáveis para a denominação da tabela (ou exibição); somente literal. Vide documentação da [cláusula FROM](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql).

Entretanto, o que você solicita talvez seja possível utilizando [variável de script](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables), pois a opção -v do utilitário [sqlcmd](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) permite o uso de algo semelhante a parâmetro.

Avalie também o uso das opções -q e -Q.

```
-- código #1 - SCRIPT arquivo.sql
SELECT * FROM $(NomeTabela)
```

e

```
-- código #2 - BATCH
sqlcmd -v NomeTabela= "TB_VENDAS_20180901" -i arquivo.sql
```

No código #2 é necessário acrescentar a parte de autenticação.
Não testei a combinação acima. Pode conter erro(s).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.